# can't call method 'on' in socket.io

Tags: node.js, terminal, socket.io

i got this error while i trying the first step to write a socket.io code, i'm actually following the guide in [the officially web of socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) and then when i run my code, in my terminal show up the error "cannot call method 'on' of undefined" in line 18. why that's happen?? i was installed the socket.io correctly before. and here is the screenshot [in here](http://i1193.photobucket.com/albums/aa344/hiatus1/socketio.png)

any suggest and advice will be appreciate it so much and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot indicates that `io.socket` doesn't exist.  From that examples page and a quick look at [the source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/manager.js#64) it would appear that perhaps you meant `io.sockets`?

`io.socket` doesn't appear to exist, hence the "cannot call method 'on' of undefined" error.

Comment: huh, yeah.. i see dude.. thanks for your answer, i'm really appreciate it for sharing your knowledge about socket.io

btw, what's the different about io.socket with io.sockets?? when the best time to use one of them?? thanks again. :)

Comment: As far as I could tell by looking quickly, there is no `io.socket`.  I haven't used socket.io personally.